Function that accepts a callable and returns a different callable with the same signature
I'm trying to write a function that receives a callable object as a parameter and returns a modified version of that callable object.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to create:
  template<class R, class... Args>
  std::function<R(Args...)> ModifyFunction(std::function<R(Args...)> f)
  {
    return [f](Args... args) {
      // Take some extra actions here...
      return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  }

It works fine if I pass a std::function object to it:
  std::function<void()> f([] {
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
  });
  auto modified = ModifyFunction(f);
  modified();

But it fails to compile if I pass a different callable type, for example, a lambda:
  auto modified = ModifyFunction([] {});
  modified();


Is it possible to write a function that will work on any callable type?
Preferably with C++11.

I recommend you take a look at how the standard library itself handles callable objects: By using a single template argument (i.e. template<typename F> std::function<F> ModfyFunction(F fun) { ... } or something similar)

related/dupe on why it fails: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586756/why-doesnt-c11-implicitly-convert-lambdas-to-stdfunction-objects

some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70468317/template-function-cannot-recognize-lambda-referred-by-an-auto-variable

@Someprogrammerdude If I use a single template argument, how can I get the Args? I need them to construct the internal lambda

@Gils Lambdas can be generic: [f](auto... args) { ... }

@NathanOliver: generic lambda is C++14, not C++11...

Woops, missed the C++11 tag.

@NathanOliver Even in C++11, you can write an equivalent generic callable: template<typename R, typename...Args> struct callable { R operator()(Args... value); }; and now if you pass a callable{}, what std::function should be deduced?

@RaymondChen The point is to not deduce a std::function and just accept any callable type.

@NathanOliver Sorry, my comment was ambiguous. I was building on your answer, not challenging it.

You might get rid of std::function and do
in C++14, we just use auto as return type:
template <typename F>
auto ModifyFunction(F f)
{
    return [f](auto... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)){
      // Take some extra actions here...
      return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}

In C++11, you might create a named class instead of the lambda
template <typename F>
class Wrapper
{
    F f;
public:
    explicit Wrapper(F f) : f(std::move(f)) {}

    template <typename...Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
         // Take some extra actions here...
         return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename F>
Wrapper<F> ModifyFunction(F f)
{
    return Wrapper<F>(f);
}

